# issue on check boxes inside listview's every child item in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, oncheckedchanged

I am working on check boxes in android, I had a listview with child having one checkbox, image, textviews and their respective onclick events. I blocked at selecting only one checkbox in the entire listview child at a time. if user wants to select other item then previously selected checkbox need to be unchecked in the listview. Please suggest me . thanks in advance.

Comment: make a global array with same size as listview for storing checkstate of checkbox with 1/0 inputs, handle 1/0 according to your need, and in getview setCheckstate for each checkbox.

Comment: Why use a checkbox when you are blocking them from selecting multiple checkboxes? Why not use [Radio Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)?